How to commit NV12 texture to FragmentShader
I want to commit nv12 texture to Flutter's FragmentShader, my app work in linux.
I just want to convert nv12 to rgba by GPU shader without CPU.
Like C/C++ I can use GL_LUMINANCE for inner format.
And Flutter Texture widget only accept rgba texture.
shader.setImageSampler(0, image);
image ?= [NV12]


